# How can I convert/deserialize JsonObject instance to a concrete class?

Tags: servicestack

I have following DTO

```
public class Foo
{
    public ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject Bar { get; set; }
}
```

`Foo.Bar` can be one out of 3 other DTOs

Somewhere in my code I would like to map/convert/deserialize `Foo.Bar` to the concrete DTO (I know that `ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject` implements `System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>` - interestingly values, which were transmitted as non-string, get into my `ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject`-instance as strings).

So I have tried

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsonExtensions.JsonTo<ConcreteDTO>(foo.Bar, ???)
```

but it takes a key-selector as the 2nd parameter - but I do not want to convert a single value, rather I would go for the whole instance.

I also know that there is `ServiceStack.Text.JsonExtensions.ConvertTo<T>(JsonObject jsonObject, Func<JsonObject, T> convertFn)`, but I do not want to convert the jsonObject handcoded.

So, how can I solve this?

EDIT:
Just to be clear - I do not want to go the detour and serialize the `JsonObject`-instance to a json-string just to deserialize it ... Is there any direct deserialization option from `JsonObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ... what I ended up with:

```
DTO concreteDTO;
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(foo.Bar);
switch (foo.ConcreteObjectType)
{
    case ObjectType.Foo1:
        concreteDTO = jsonString.FromJson<DTO1>();
        break;
    case ObjectType.Foo2:
        concreteDTO = jsonString.FromJson<DTO2>();
        break;
    case ObjectType.Foo3:
        concreteDTO = jsonString.FromJson<DTO3>();
        break;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a very good option. Each time you derive a new concrete type, you'll have to add another case option.

Comment: @ant but that's the case of a factory/mapper whatever - what other chance do you have? the linkage must be known *somewhere*, and everytime you introduce a new type you'll have to adapt this *somewhere* ... if you make a registry for that: somehwere are the register-calls... if you make an array with key=type and value=factory method: somewhere are the `push`-calls ... the main problem in my case is: i am dealing with `enums` - if i'd have classes/complex types i could introduce some `abstract`/`virtual` properties to achieve this factory ... but i am dealing with values ... sad but true ...

Comment: years later - to conclude - you should rather use a strategy pattern approach ...